# Is there similar functionality in Python REPL to Scala's REPL to reference a previous computation?

Tags: python, scala, read-eval-print-loop

I've started to like Scala REPL's ability to reference previous computations with resX and wanted to know if there's a way to access that in Python/bpython/iPython REPL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default python interpreter manipulates a variable by the name `_` to have the last returned value (including `None` for expressions that return it).  iPython extends this to `__` and `___` as well as `Out`, which is a dict containing all of the returned results.

This feature is present *only* in interactive interpreters, though.  In a regular python module, `_` is undefined (unless you define it).

Comment: ipython also allows `_N` where `N` is the history number of the results you want

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this python startup script (Python will look for a export `PYTHONSTARTUP`variable, which should contain the path to script, e.g `$HOME/.pythonrc.py`):

- http://peadrop.com/blog/2007/04/15/boosted-python-startup/

As backup:

```
h = [None]  # history

class Prompt:
    """A prompt a history mechanism.
    From http://www.norvig.com/python-iaq.html
    """
    def __init__(self, prompt='h[%d] >>> '):
        self.prompt = prompt

    def __str__(self):
        try:
            if _ not in h: h.append(_)
        except NameError:
            pass
        return self.prompt % len(h)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return str(other) + str(self)

sys.ps1 = Prompt()
sys.ps2 = '     ... '
```

Usage:

```
h[1] >>> lambda x: x * 2
<function <lambda> at 0xb7dab41c>
h[2] >>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
h[3] >>> map(h[1], h[2])
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: Wow this was answered so quickly, I'm unable to even accept your answer! Thanks so much!!